# Error: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android-studio, android, gson

> Process: com.example.venky.httpurl1, PID: 2578
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $[0]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rtlist);
    client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(MainActivity.this, url, new com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            String responsestr = new String(responseBody);
            gson = new Gson();
            responseObj = gson.fromJson(responsestr, Response.class);
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, responseObj);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

ANy inputs please??
Is it because of my JSON data ??

Answer (score 0):

Check if `responseBody` is `NULL` or Empty before converting it to String and parsing it as `JSON` value

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rtlist);
    client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(MainActivity.this, url, new com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if(responseBody != null && responseBody.length > 0) {
                String responsestr = new String(responseBody);
                gson = new Gson();
                responseObj = gson.fromJson(responsestr, Response.class);
                adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, responseObj);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
```